# If $O(A)=2$ and $O(B)=3$, then the number of possible $R:A\to B$ is:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $O(A)=2$ and $O(B)=3$, then the number of possible $R:A\to B$ is:

I couldn't get any idea. However, I guess $2\times 3=6$ is the number of functions from $A\to B$. But what's the number of relations?

Comment: Remember that a relation is defined as a subset of the cartesian product $A\times B$.  How many elements are in $A\times B$?  How many subsets are there of an $n$ element set?  How many subsets then are there and as a result how many relations are there from $A$ to $B$?  (*Hint: the power set of a set $X$ is often denoted as $2^X$ instead of as $\mathcal{P}(X)$ for a reason*)

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ are often denoted as $B^A$... there are in fact $3^2=9$ possible functions from $A$ to $B$, not $6$.

Comment: What does $O(A)$ mean?

Comment: @DeepSea given the context, I'm quite sure that it represents to this user the order of the set, or rather the cardinality of the set.  There is the chance that I'm wrong of course, but it seems unlikely in this case.

Comment: @DeepSea,JMoravitz, $O(A)$ represents the.number of elements in set A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $O(A\times B) = 6 \implies n = 2^6 = 64$ relations in total.

Comment: Could you please explain what formula and concepts have you used?

Comment: But the answer in book is $2^6$.??